# Unable to create environments on Google Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I tried to create a Google Cloud Composer environment but in the page to set it up I get the following errors:

```
 Service Error: Failed to load GKE machine types. Please leave the field
    empty to apply default values or retry later. 

 Service Error: Failed to load regions. Please leave the field empty to
    apply default values or retry later. 

 Service Error: Failed to load zones. Please leave the field empty to apply
    default values or retry later. 

Service Error: Failed to load service accounts. Please leave the field
    empty to apply default values or retry later.
```

The only parameters GCP lets me change are the region and the number of nodes, but still lets me create the environment. After 30 minutes the environment crashes with the following error:

```
CREATE operation on this environment failed 1 day ago with the following error message:
Http error status code: 400
Http error message: BAD REQUEST
Errors in: [Web server]; Error messages:
    Failed to deploy the Airflow web server. This might be a temporary issue. You can retry the operation later.
If the issue persists, it might be caused by problems with permissions or network configuration. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/troubleshooting-environment-creation.

An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2021-07-20T14:31:23.047Z7050.xd.0: Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back. If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the 'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.

Got error "Another operation failed." during CP_DEPLOYMENT_CREATING_STANDARD []
```

Is it a problem with permissions? If so, what permissions do I need? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like more of a temporary issue:

1. the first set of errors is stating you cannot load the metadata :
   regions list, zones list ....
2. you dont have a clear
   PERMISSION_DENIED error
3. the second error: is suggesting also:
   `This might be a temporary issue.`

Comment: Thank you, but I have been having this problem for the last 2 weeks. I have logged in GCP with another account (in which I am the project owner) and I was able to create  environments with no problems, but I was not getting the Service Errors and GCP let me change all options, this is why I thought about permissions or maybe some project settings.

Comment: Did you check the settings of your project? There are some policies that must be configured appropriately to create environments.(https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/troubleshooting-environment-creation#incompatible_organizational_policies) It is very common that the creation fails when there are incompatible settings. 2. Are you using the default service account of Compute Engine? If not, what permission or role does it have?

Comment: @steu When using the Owner account were you able to create a Composer environment in the same project as the one failing before? Usually, errors like these come up when some default service accounts are deleted or modified. That would affect the owner account as well though. If you don't have other environments running, you could try disabling and re-enabling the Composer API.